# Как в функции высшего порядка изменить параметр передаваемой функции

Tags: javascript

Напишите функцию высшего порядка myHiOrderFunction, которая принимает в качестве 1 аргумента другую функцию, например, sayName, и применяет ее ко всем остальным
аргументам. При данном коде функция высшего порядка возвращает строку только с одним именем. К примеру в третьем случае "Я - Иван". Как можно сделать так, что бы отображались все имена,  не меня параметр функции sayName(...name). Я написал так,  но суть в том что я могу передавать в функцию высшего порядка сколько угодно аргументов, но функция которую она возвращает принимает только 1 параметр

```js
function sayName(name) {
alert(`Я - ${name}`);
};
function miHiOrderFunction(func, ...arg) {
 return sayName(...arg);
};
miHiOrderFunction(sayName, 'Вася');
miHiOrderFunction(sayName, 'Петя', 'Маша', 'John');
miHiOrderFunction(sayName, 'Иван', 'Слава', 'Крис', 'Толя');
```

Comment: `return args.map(sayName)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function sayName(name) {
  alert(`Я - ${name}`);
};

function miHiOrderFunction(func, ...args) {
  return args.map(func);
};

miHiOrderFunction(sayName, 'Вася');
miHiOrderFunction(sayName, 'Петя', 'Маша', 'John');
miHiOrderFunction(sayName, 'Иван', 'Слава', 'Крис', 'Толя');
```

Обрабатываем каждый элемент через map и возвращаем новый массив.